# Currency formatting incorrectly on Membership Renewal Reminders

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

Since the upgrade to civiCRM 5.1.3 our email Membership Renewal reminders have been coming out with membership_fee formatting incorrectly i.e. $80.00 is displaying as $80.000000000
I've tried changing the parameters in the Localization settings but nothing seems to make any difference. Could this be a Drupal problem instead?
Anyone seen this before and got ideas or suggestions? thanks.

Comment: You mention 5.1.3 - I assume you are now on critical security release 5.3.1 (actually 5.3.2 is dropping today with some minor fixes to that so if not on 5.3.1 yet wait til 5.3.2 drops)

Comment: I have seen the same behaviour on 5.3.1 but had not yet time to investigate it. Wat worked in my case was to change the fee on membership type, and then to change it back to the correct amount.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, on 5.3.2 under Drupal. I thought it was the same problem as fixed in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12186/files but this patch to CRM/Utils/Token.php is in place in 5.3.2, so not that. Does Schedule Reminders go through a different route from Print/Merge Documents (which works correctly)?

Comment: Upgraded to 5.4 and still seeing this problem. I was going to try and setup Reminder as Plain text only but getting a message saying there must be an HTML version. Why's that? Documentation seems very patchy in this area

Comment: Is this using the offline membership signup/receipt message template?  I wonder if this is related to your PHP environment at all - depending on how the scheduled jobs are run?  Eg. from within CiviCRM or via cron.